# SignalR hub context from web app is not calling a client( console app) method

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to call a console app method from SignalR HUB context which is not working-

```
 var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hubsfile.MyHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.SendControl(machine, code);
```

This (another function below) is working fine as the client is the webpage itself(i think).

> hubContext.Clients.All.registerCard(ip, data);

But when I am trying to call a method that is from different client(a console application) , Hub context is not calling it.

Does Hub context doesnt work for clients outside of the Hub Application.

Edit:

Method in SignalR HUB:

```
public void SendControlKeys(string machine, string code)
    {
        Clients.All.SendControl(machine, code);
    }
```

Method in Console client:

```
  proxy.On<string, string>("SendControl", (ip, data) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("server called SendControl");
                Console.WriteLine();
                byte[] dataBytes = HexEncoding.GetBytes(data, out int i);
                try
                {
                    lock (Clients)
                    {
                        if (Clients.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StateObject> client in Clients)
                            {
                                if (isClientConnected(client.Value.workSocket))
                                {
                                    if (client.Key == ip)
                                    {
                                        Send(client.Value.workSocket, dataBytes);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            });
```

Comment: have you connected to the signalr hub from the console client?

Comment: @reckface yes... The console client is sending data to hub. No issues with that.. The issue is only... when I am trying to call that console method from my control.aspx.cs(code behind) file using hub context. And that hub context can call the javascript client function., so I think there is no syntax error also. So I dont know where is the error.. as there is no exception or error shown from signalR or any other code part.

Comment: what's the name of the method on the console application. can you paste the signature in your question?

Comment: @reckface I have added methods in the question for refrence

Comment: So your `proxy.Start(); // await or .Wait()` is called after this call to `proxy.On<T>()`?

Comment: @reckface..no... I have this steps connection start.wait() before this proxy.on() call to function.....`con = new HubConnection("http://localhost:17263/"); proxy = con.CreateHubProxy("myHub"); Console.WriteLine("connecting to server"); con.Start().Wait(); Console.WriteLine("connected");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the hub connection's `Start()` method after setting up the callback on the proxy.

```
var proxy = con.CreateHubProxy("name");
proxy.On<T>(...);
con.Start().Wait();
```

Then, **use a single parameter** in your callback. Wrap the 2 parameters you have into a single class/object.

Apart from that, ensure the name of the hub in your CreateHubProxy call is valid, that is the name of the SignalR Hub in your ASP.net application (in your case `MyHub`).

Comment: I am going to try this now... And will let you know

Comment: Amazing... It worked like magic... Just used con.start.wait() after proxy.On(). Thank you so much.. You saved my tons of time.. life savior... i would have not been able to catch this thing this soon.. So thank you...